# Using Callback function with lambda in typescript with void

Tags: typescript, lambda, return

How do I read the following function in typescript

```
insertDocuments(collectionName: string, content: any[], callback: (error: string, result: any) => void) {

}
```

It makes sense if we don't have the "=> void" at the end like

```
insertDocuments(collectionName: string, content: any[], callback: (error: string, result: any)) {

}
```

So that means that we have a function which takes 3 parameters and the last is the callback parameter. But what does ***void*** get us in the above function. Does that mean we cannot have explicit "return" statement within the function?

Comment: yeah, it's a function that doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost, it means that the function's return value will not be used by the consumers of `callback`, you can still pass a callback with a return value, the return value would just be ignored (and you'd get a type error if you try to use it).